# Prove $\int_{2}^{\infty}\ln\sec\frac{\pi}{x}\,dx$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have proved that  $\int_{2}^{3}\ln\sec\frac{\pi}{x}\,dx$ is convergent by first proving that $$\sec x\leq\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{\pi}x}$$ and therefore proving that if $\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{x}}\,dx$ converges then $\int_{2}^{3}\ln\sec\frac{\pi}{x}\,dx$ converges. I am stuck now on how to prove that $\int_{3}^{\infty}\ln\sec\frac{\pi}{x}\,dx$ converges. I have tried using limit comparison test with $\sec\frac{\pi}{x}-1$ but I can't prove that $\int_{3}^{\infty}\left(\sec\frac{\pi}{x}-1\right)dx$ converges either.

Comment: Hint: use l'Hopital's rule to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(\sec t)}{t^2}$. What does that tell you about the behavior of $\ln(\sec \frac\pi x)$ as $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos y \geq 1-\frac {y^{2}} 2$ for all $y \geq 0$. [Proof: $(\cos y - 1+\frac {y^{2}} 2)'=-\sin y +y\geq 0$ and $\cos y - 1+\frac {y^{2}} 2$ vanishes when $y=0$].

Hence, on $(\pi, \infty)$ we have $ln (\sec \frac {\pi} x)=-\ln (\cos  \frac {\pi} x)\leq -ln (1- (\frac {\pi} x)^{2}))$. Now I  will let you finish using the inequality $-\ln (1-t) =\ln (\frac 1 {1-t})=\ln [1+\frac t {1-t}] \leq \frac t {1-t}$.